# can we communicate using mac address?

Tags: networking, mac-address, arp

I got a question 
Can we communicate with only using mac address with a computer which is in my network?

So i said yes.
Because when we communicating using arp protocol we only use mac address.

I want to know whether my answer and justification is right or not?

Answer (score -1):

You are correct.  ARP does communicate on the same subnet using MAC addresses.  Your answer could be improved to include that the computers have to be on the same subnet.  It could be further improved to reveal that a router can be attacked so that it turns into a switch and opens its subnets on wired and wireless to reside on the same subnet as far as ARP is concerned.  The attacks are ARP flooding and ARP poisoning.